# Syntax of DXH 'CBSvcHost.exe.config' <Host> section in Ektron 9

Tags: ektron

My error ;**Connction is not showing in drop down list** of workarea

i have add a new connection in ektron 8.7 dxh , its working fine, but when i add the code to **ektron 9 dxh its not working** ,i think some syntax had changed in host section , please tell how solve the issue.

```
 <add serviceName="Name Connector" serviceType="namespace.classname, dllfilename, Version=1.2.0.074, Culture=neutral" />
```

```
<add serviceName="name Connector" serviceType="namespace.classname, dllfilename, Culture=neutral" />
```

my observation:

```
1. no version section 
2.  can we use dot(.) extension in "dllfilename" {is working in 8.7 but not working in 9} eg:(Ektron.custom) as dll file name
```

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My observation was wrong ,The problem is referencing dll files,Means i was referencing ektron 8.7 files like ContextBus.dll etc.Thanks to my team leader